Retrieved document score returns 1.0 (100% relevant) when Weaviate is used with LlamaIndex
I refer to my question posted in https://forum.weaviate.io/t/retrieved-document-score-returns-1-0-100-relevant-when-used-with-llamaindex/2396
I am building a RAG pipeline using LlamaIndex and Weaviate as the vector database. I referred to the setup guide based on LlamaIndex documentation here Weaviate Vector Store - LlamaIndex
When performing a query with the query engine, it returns a tuple containing the response and the source nodes. The source nodes contains information such as file metadata and score.
The raw format of score is between 0 to 1, where 0 is irrelevant and 1 is exactly relevant.
When using LlamaIndex inbuilt-memory database, it can provide somewhat correct scores between 0.5 to 0.8. However, when I connected with Weaviate as the database, the score only returned as 1.
Below is the setup information:
Server Setup Information
Weaviate Version: 1.24.0 (hosted on Docker)
LlamaIndex Version: 0.10.13.post1
Weaviate Setup:
Weaviate is hosted on Docker. To connect to the Weaviate database on python:
import weaviate
client = connect_to_local()

Create a Weaviate collection
from weaviate.classes.config import Configure, VectorDistances, Property, DataType
index_name = "LlamaIndex"
collection = client.collections.create(
  index_name,
  properties=[
    Property(name="title", data_type=DataType.TEXT, index_filterable=True, index_searchable=True),
    Property(name="title", data_type=DataType.TEXT, index_filterable=True, index_searchable=True),
  ],
  vectorizer_config=Configure.Vectorizer.text2vec_transformers(),
  vector_index_config(Configure.VectorIndex.hnsw(distance_metric=VecotrDistances.COSINE),
  reranker_config=Configure.Reranker.transformers(),
  inverted_index_config=Configure.inverted_index(
    bm25_b=0.7,
    bm25_k1=1.25,
    index_null_state=True,
    index_property_length=True,
    index_timestamps=True
  ),
)

Ingesting document data into Weaviate, and create an Index using LlamaIndex
from llama_index.vector_stores.weaviate import WeaviateVectorStore
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index.core import StorageContext

# load documents
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("./data/paul_graham").load_data()

vector_store = WeaviateVectorStore(
    weaviate_client=client, index_name="LlamaIndex"
)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
    documents, storage_context=storage_context
)

Assuming the setup is already done and ready for user to query, below is to print the document score:
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("Did the author live on Mars?")

source_nodes = response.source_nodes
for node in source_nodes:
    print(node.score)  # It printed 1.0

